# Send curl request with form values using PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have a page like this:

```
<form action method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="rand" value="casualnumbers">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I need to get the result page, sending with CURL the "rand" value as POST variable.

I know how to send POST variables using:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("rand" => "casualnumbers")
```

But how can I take the "casualnumbers" from the form page?

The page generates a random value and the post request works only if it gets the right random value, so I need to take the random value from the page and immediately send the post request with the right random value

Comment: Do you mean how to use `$_POST['casualnumbers']`?

Comment: Maybe should explain what you are trying to do. Do you want to parse another page first to it's content as POST params?

Comment: The page generates a random value and the post request works only if it gets the right random value, so I need to take the random value from the page and immediately send the post request with the right random vlaue

Comment: First you need to fetch html with CURL (cookie support), parse that field value, and POST with CURL + previously fetched cookies.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I use:

```
 preg_match_all('/<input.*type="(submit|hidden)".*name="([^"]+)".*value="([^"]*)".*>/u',$form_html,$vars);
$post_vars=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($vars[2]);$i++)
    $post_vars[$vars[2][$i]]=$vars[3][$i];
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_vars);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do I need to se file_get_contents so?

Comment: What are you asking? The input variable is $form_html if it's that.

Comment: And how do you want to get it? Is it a webpage or what?